# Ошибка ли в пунктуации, напряжёнка ли со смыслом?

Tags: пунктуация

> Сегодня познакомилась с человеком из Гамбии. Эта африканская страна
>   лежит вдоль берегов одной из крупнейших рек Сенегала.

Час волка: голова не варит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...находится внутри страны Сенегал, которой эта река не принадлежит (кроме небольшого участка у истока).

На самом деле истоки реки Гамбии в (стране) Гвинее, по ней она протекает порядка 150 км, затем течёт по Сенегалу и потом попадает в узкую полоску страны Гамбии, окружающей её, течёт по ней с востока на запад и впадает в Атлантику. И к Сенегалу относится не небольшой участок, а очень даже приличный, по длине практически равный её гамбийской части — обе части длиной 450–500 км. Совершенно верно, что *"геометрически всё вместе находится внутри страны Сенегал" (гамбийская часть реки и окружающая её территория Гамбии),* но всё-таки эта часть не относится к Сенегалу, поэтому в предложении *"Эта африканская страна лежит вдоль берегов одной из крупнейших рек Сенегала"* река считается одной из крупнейших в Сенегале, видимо, только по той части, что по нему протекает, и не считается часть, вокруг которой он геометрически располагается.

Answer (score 1):

Эта африканская страна расположена по берегам одноимённой реки, одной из крупнейших на Чёрном континенте.

Comment: Мишель, а что карты подсказывают (я не ориентируюсь)? Гамбия не на реке Гамбии, а на реке Сенегал?

Comment: Вот. https://www.google.ru/maps/place/Гамбия/@13.4075574,-17.6133369,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xec29c2965af3807:0x9e4a4c406b139d2a!8m2!3d13.443182!4d-15.310139 Государство расположено между 13 и 14° с. ш. в Западной Африке, имеет форму полосы длиной около 400 км, простирающейся по обе стороны реки Гамбия, ширина полосы в основном варьируется от 24 до 28 км, в устье — 45 км. На востоке, севере и юге имеет границу с Республикой Сенегал, общая протяжённость границы — 740 км.

Comment: Римхен-Лорхен, на карте - очень вразумительной - про реку непонятно. Мне, бестолке. Нет ли "ошибки по факту": река Гамбия - река Сенегал.

Comment: По обе стороны реки Гамбия. Государство Сенегал — вокруг.

Comment: ААА! А с этим что делать: *Эта африканская страна <Гамбия> лежит вдоль берегов одной из крупнейших рек Сенегала*? Может, река Гамбия - приток етого Сенегала?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Гамбия_(река) Все, помчалась на работу. Всех благ!

Comment: ААА! *По территории Сенегала протекают две крупные реки с постоянным течением — Сенегал на севере и Казаманс на юге. Большинство остальных рек почти полностью пересыхают в сухое время года.* Никакой приточной Гамбии!

Comment: Ошибся я, ошибся. Оскандалился. Ликуйте, злые люди.

Comment: Кстати, Галина, не Мишель, а Майкл. :)

Comment: Ну, написано ваще Микаэль... А я уже по-разному обзывалась, Майклушко тож среди прочих был, и, как видишь, до сих пор не пристукнута. )))

Comment: *Ну, написано ваще Микаэль...* @GalinaAvanesova: английский Майкл именно так и пишется, а французский Мишель пишется Michel (и так же читающееся женское Michelle). Спасибо, кстати, что ответ приняли. ;)

Comment: Посмотрел, как по-английски пишут Микаэля Таривердиева — Mikael.

Comment: @Michael_1812 Зачем Чёрный континент понизил?! Ошибка ж!

Comment: поправил, merci

Answer (score 1):

Со смыслом запутали: реально Гамбия тянется полоской вдоль реки Гамбия, и геометрически всё вместе находится внутри *страны* Сенегал, которой эта река *не* принадлежит (кроме небольшого участка у истока).

Comment: Гамбия вытянулась по берегам Сенегала? Я никак не найду ея там...

Comment: И меня запутали! Поправил.

Comment: Может, лучше просклонять реку Гамбию — вроде давно освоенное название?

Comment: Можно "одноименной рекой" её упомянуть.

Comment: Вот про это и сказано было: напряжёнка ли со смыслом, час волка... )))